# Evaluate a prediction's accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I've trained and tested my KNN classifier. I've crossed validated it and the mean score is decent. Now, I would like to predict labels for some real data. But is there a way of seeing the accuracy of a prediction? I would like to actually save the predicted label only if the accuracy is high enough. I'm using Python and scikit-learn.

Comment: Have you checked the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) there are lots of ways to evaluate your model

Comment: What do you mean by accuracy? Do you mean how many of the classifier's classifications match the real data (in which case you will need a point of truth to compare it to), or how certain the classifier is of each classification it makes?

Comment: @EdChum, I did, but that's model evaluation, not a prediction evaluation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I would like to know how certain is the classifier about the label it predicted. Say if prediction A has 90% accuracy, it's a good bet it's correct and I will save it to my database.

Comment: @AndreiHorak have you looked at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.predict_proba?

Comment: I did, but I'm not sure how much it helps me. Basically I need to first use `predict()`, then `predict_proba()`, zip the results and for each item see if the corresponding label has a score above, say, 0.9? Is this how it should be done?

Comment: `predict_proba()` would be my suggestion too, it should return a probability score for each class, you could then compare this against the train and test data and check if the predicted label probability score is above 90%

Comment: @AndreiHorak yes, that's exactly what I'd suggest

Comment: OK then, if two suggest the same thing, I'll go with this. You can submit an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: You might be interested in looking into the new calibration module, to see how good the probability estimates are that your KNN returns.

Comment: @AndreasMueller, can you give further details on this? I'm not sure how the calibration could help.

Comment: Look at the calibration_curve. If it is very far from diagonal, the probability estimates will not be very reliable, and you might want to use CallibratedClassifierCV.

Comment: I need to use an algorithm or something, I can't/won't be able to watch a graph and then input something based on it.

Answer (score 2):

As @jonrsharpe said, `predict_proba` should do it.

It provide an array with all the probabilities of the categories. Lets say, you have 3 categories [A, B, C]. The `predict_proba` method will return 
[0.2,0.3,0.5]. 
So here your accuracy would be

```
A=0.2
B=0.3
C=0.5
```

For example :

```
categories = [A, B, C]
X = # put your data
Y = # put your result

classifier.fit(X, Y)
prediction = classifier.predict_proba(X) # predict whatever you want here

for line in prediction:
    # numpy.argmax return the index of the biggest value in the array
    # max return the biggest value
    print("The class is %s with proba : %f " % (categories[numpy.argmax(line)], max(line, key=float)))
```

**Important** : take care of the order in your categories array. The content of the predict_proba results are sorted lexically based on the categories. Don't hesitate to sort categories before treating the result

Comment: The classifier will also have a ``classes_`` attribute that gives you the order that was used.